# perform browser action with node.js with using API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do some event eg. clicks in a website. I can do it in chrome with javascript (or chrome extension), but is it possible to do without opening chrome but with server side code? No API is provided. It's not scraping but perform some sort of action.

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS uses [Google V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/v8/) to interpret the JavaScript code. It does not run in a browser environment and therefore it lacks DOM and event handling. However, you can actually mock browser in NodeJS environment using [mock-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser) package.

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser/lib/MockBrowser')

const mockBrowser = new MockBrowser()

global.window = mockBrowser.getWindow()
global.document = mockBrowser.getDocument()
global.navigator = mockBrowser.getNavigator()
```

However, you should be careful with this approach, as some methods (e.g. [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)) still will not work.

Maybe you should reconsider why you want to use DOM and events on the server side.

## PhantomJS: Headless browser for NodeJS

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) for NodeJS that is used for testing, scraping, etc. It provides you with a full-featured browser that can simulate a browser.

## Using CasperJS for scraping

If you want to scrape websites, you may use a library called [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) that itself uses PhantomJS. An example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var links;

function getLinks() {
// Scrape the links from top-right nav of the website
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('ul.navigation li a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href')
    });
}

// Opens casperjs homepage
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function () {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.run(function () {
    for(var i in links) {
        console.log(links[i]);
    }
    casper.done();
});
```

Comment: `Maybe you should reconsider why you want to use DOM and events on the server side.`

because that is the only way to trigger an event?

Comment: @Nately Jamerson: Trigger events on what? Why do you need DOM on the server side?

Comment: I have bunch of links, I want to trigger click on certain button on the sites, can you do it without trigger the DOM? No API is provided.

Comment: I have bunch of links, I want to trigger click on certain button on the sites without going to cilent side, can you do it without trigger the DOM? No API is provided.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson What you are looking for is not possible by NodeJS itself, but you can use PhantomJS package in NodeJS to do it. I updated the answer.